# Access properties from object with variable in Java

Tags: java

```
public class myClass {
    private Object myObject;

    public myClass() {
        myObject = new myObjectClass();
    }

    private class myObjectClass {
        private int A = 1;
        private int B = 5;
    }

    public int getMyObjectValue(String id) {
        return myObject.[[[[id]]]];
    }
}
```

I want to get `myObject` property like this: `myClass.getMyObjectValue("A")`

In `Javascript` we can just do `myObject[id];`

How can I transform `return myObject.[[[[id]]]];` to make it work ?

Comment: Not very easily. You'll need to use reflection. So the question is *why* you want to do that. What kind of problem are you trying to solve with this structure?

Comment: You could let myObject be a Map instead but the question is what the purpose is with this approach.

Comment: Can you modify the class? If yes, you could define an enum inside the class `public enum PROPERTY_NAME{ A, B; }` and have a getter that accepts that enum, switches between the enum cases and returns the desired property.
If however you can't modify the class, I'm afraid what @RealSkeptic suggested (reflection) is the only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more about reflection https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

```
Object someObject = myObject();
for (Field field : someObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    field.setAccessible(true); // You might want to set modifier to public first.
    Object value = field.get(someObject); 
    if (value != null) {
        System.out.println(field.getName() + "=" + value);
    }
}
```